# iOS: Customize App Icon and Splash Screen via Enterprise (In-House) Distribution

Tags: ios, distribution, info.plist, ipa, in-house-distribution

When deploying an App via the Enterprise Developer Programs In-House Distribution there is a .plist file acting as descriptor for the .ipa file.

Does anyone know if it is possible to change standard info.plist values via this file?

The background is that I want to adjust the App Icon and Splash Screen. I want to customize the app for different customers without recompiling it. If the above approach is not possible what else can I do to ease that process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to customize the app for different customers without recompiling it.

Not possible. The app is signed before you distribute it. Any change will invalidate the signature and the device will refuse to run it. You'll need to recompile if you want to change things like the app icon.

The splash screen is somewhat different. You can't change the default image, but you can omit the default image and display your own splash screen as soon as the app is loaded. That screen can contain an image that you download from a server, for example.

Give that you're talking about enterprise distribution, I think the best plan is to simply create separate targets in your project, one for each customized version. Each target would reference different icon and default image files. You can even create an aggregate target, so that all the customized versions are built at the same time.

Instructions for adding a customized target, assuming Xcode 4:

- Select the project in the project navigator.
- Click the Add Target button at the bottom of the detail area, or just select the target and use the Edit->Duplicate command.
- Make a copy of the Info.plist file from your first target and add it to the project.
- Select the new target and change it's "Info.plist" setting in the Packaging section of Build Settings. (You may also want to adjust the product name.)

To add an aggregate target that builds all the others, add a target using the Aggregate target template (under Other in the template picker). Then select the new aggregate target, click Build Phases, and add all your other targets as target dependencies.

Comment: How do you do that? You have different targets? Are there any templates/scripts I could use? Problem is that my customer will need to adjust App Icon/Splash Screen to distribute to HIS customers and they don't want to install xcode and do the whole "developer" kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed talking about Enterprise Distribution. Thanks for the clarification and hints. That was more or less what I expected. Do you think that the simulated "Splash Screen" that I show after loading could create a completely similar experience to a real splash screen?

Comment: I've added instructions to the answer above. If your customer doesn't want to do the recompilation, I'd call that an opportunity.

Comment: As for splash screens, you should know that the default image mechanism really was never meant to be used as a splash screen in the first place. The default image is intended to give the impression that the app is starting more quickly -- you put a picture of your empty UI there, so it looks like the app launches very quickly and is just working on populating the UI with data. So go ahead and use it that way, and then display a view with your "splash" information in a smaller view on top when the app does launch.

Comment: I know what Apple states about the default image but it's what the customers want.